# poetry install - ParseConstraintError Could not parse version constraint: install ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, python-poetry

I am working with python poetry, to know about it [refer](https://python-poetry.org/).
While installing it I didnt get any issue, [command](https://python-poetry.org/docs/).
Poetry was able to install the packages, however it was getting stuck in between.
I tried to do multiple solutions present on the stack overflow and on google. Again nothing worked.
Now I`m getting the following error:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Project_File\backend> poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

  ParseConstraintError                                                                                              
                                                                                                                    
  Could not parse version constraint: install                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\core\semver\__init__.py:149 in parse_single_constraint
      145│             return VersionUnion(VersionRange(max=version), VersionRange(min=version))                    
      146│         else:                                                                                            
      147│             return version                                                                               
      148│                                                                                                          
    → 149│     raise ParseConstraintError(                                                                          
      150│         "Could not parse version constraint: {}".format(constraint)                                      
      151│     )                                                                                                    
      152│
```

I found some related error questions on stack overflow:
[Could not parse version constraint ~x.x: Invalid version string "~x.x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242924/could-not-parse-version-constraint-x-x-invalid-version-string-x-x) . 
Though I`m not able to figure out how could I solve my issue.

If anyone from the community could support would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this issue seems to have been triggered with the latest version of poetry, 1.2.1. Downgrading to 1.1.12 fixed it.

Comment: To downgrade version, run "pip install poetry==1.1.12"

Answer (score 0):

I by mistake edited the poetry.lock file.
Just rollbacked the changes(In that I updated the Poetry version) and then run `poetry install`.

The aforementioned error got fixed.